# Override -(void)parentViewController to return custom view controller. And avoid type casting in future...?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a `@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController`. I wonder if it is possible to do this:

```
-(CustomViewController*)parentViewController{
      return /* bla bla return custom vc here*/; 
}
```

As you can see, I want to simply override `-(UIViewController*)parentViewController` but to return an instance of `CustomViewController`.

Obviously, I can simply create another property like `customParentViewContrller` and everything will be fine. However, I really don't want to do this, because I will end up using two properties, which actually represent the same thing - not good.

Edit:
Let me clear this. I want to avoid type casting in future so that this code `[(CustomViewController*)self.parentViewController someCustomProperty]`

turns to this code

`[self.parentViewController someCustomProperty]`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can..

Created a basic project and tested it out:

```
- (ViewController *)parentViewController {
    return self;
}
```

Working fine.